# Is “I killed him who carried a gun” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, personal-pronouns

This is a grammatically correct sentence:

> It is him who carried a gun.

-

But this one:

> I killed him who carried a gun.

sounds a little odd.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: A good question!  I would say it's "grammatically correct, but very stilted and old-fashioned".  It is allowable to use a restrictive clause like "who carried a gun" with a personal pronoun, but it's not something we do very often in modern, informal speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native speakers will say:

> It's him who had the gun.<sup>colloquial</sup>
>
> It is he who had the gun.<sup>formal</sup>

Your second sentence would be unusual. Instead of **him**, we would probably say "the man" or "the one".

> There were two bank robbers. One of them was unarmed. The police shot the one who had a gun.

You will find examples of a relative clause headed by **who** modifying **him**, but this does not occur in contemporary conversational English; today it  appears in literary contexts emulating older forms of the language:

> Let him who is without sin cast the first stone.

Comment: Good answer, but I think this general construction (first two examples), would be pretty uncommon in any speech.  People would more likely say "He is the one who had the gun."

Comment: The first example I gave is very common in the patois of southeastern PA, where I come from. The meaning is "Don't look at *me* -- *he's* the one who ... ."